# Getting data from custom list view on click

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView with two TextViews both containing different values. What I want to be able to do it get the contents from one of these TextViews when an item is clicked.

This is the code I have so far:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
String value;
// value = (get value of TextView here)
     }
});
```

I want to be able to assign `value` to the text of one of the TextView's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although @Sam's suggestions will work fine in most scenarios, I actually prefer using the supplied `AdapterView` in `onItemClick(...)` for this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Person person = (Person) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    // ...
}
```

I consider this to be a slightly more fool-proof approach, as the `AdapterView` will take into account any header views that may potentially be added using [`ListView.addHeaderView(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29).

For example, if your `ListView` contains one header, tapping on the first item supplied by the adapter will result in the `position` variable having a value of `1` (rather than `0`, which is the default case for no headers), since the header occupies position `0`. Hence, it's very easy to mistakenly retrieve the wrong data for a position and introduce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the last list item. By retrieving the item from the `AdapterView`, the position is automatically correctly offset. You can of course manually correct it too, but why not use the tools provided? :)

Just FYI and FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options. I reference the code from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14013833/1267661).

- You can access this data from the row's layout `view`:

  ```
  ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
  // Now use holder.name.getText().toString() and holder.description as you please
  ```
- You can access the Adapter with `position`:

  ```
  Person person = mAdapter.getItem(position);
  // Now use person.name and person.description as you please
  ```

(By the way in your Person class, `name` and `description` are `public` so you don't need the get methods.)

Answer (score 0):

Override following method in adaterclass.

```
public String[] getText() {
        return text;
    }
```